# Computing the Dimension of a Polynomial Ring

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, extremal-combinatorics

I am currently reading "Polynomial Methods in Combinatorics" by Prof. Larry Guth of M.I.T., where I came across a dimensional argument I couldn't quite understand.

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ denote a field of $q$ elements, and $Poly_D(\mathbb{F}^n)$ be the space of polynomials in the ring $\mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n]$ with dimension $\leq{D}$ and coefficients in $\mathbb{F}^n$, such that $Poly_D(\mathbb{F}^n)\subset\mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n]$. Note that $Poly_D(\mathbb{F}^n)$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}^n_q$.   We use a "Stars and Bars" encoding to compute the dimension of the space $Poly_D(\mathbb{F}^n)$. Fix $D$ and $n$. We encode the monomial $x_1^{D_1}\cdot...\cdot{x_n^{D_n}}$ by first writing $D_1$ $*$'s (meaning if $D_1=5$, we place 5 $*$'s), and placing one bar directly after. We do this until we have $D_n$ $*$'s followed directly by the $n$th bar. At the end of the encoding, if we did not max out the degree of the monomial, we add $D-\sum{D_i}\space\ast$'s.

Example: We encode $x^3y^2z^2$ in $Poly_9(\mathbb{F})$ by $\ast\ast\ast|\ast\ast|\ast\ast|\ast\ast$ .

This encoding is a bijection between the monomials of $Poly_D(\mathbb{F}^n)$ and the $\ast$'s and |'s. Clearly, we have $D+n$ "slots" where we can place our $\ast$'s and |'s. Because we have $n$ variables to place in our monomial, the number of arrangements we can have between the variables and their degrees is ${D+n}\choose{n}$.

Guth then concludes that $Dim(Poly_D(\mathbb{F}^n))={{D+n}\choose{n}}$. 
I'm not sure why the number of monomials is the exact dimension, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Because the monomials generate the vector space?

Comment: @KennyLau Is it because linear combinations of the monomials are used to form all the polynomials?

Comment: Right.$ $$ $$ $

Comment: @KennyLau Would you call this a basis for the space? Not sure if polynomial rings have bases since they aren't free algebras.

Comment: It is a vector space and every vector space has a basis.

Comment: @KennyLau I see thanks for your help. One last thing that I'm curious about: If there wasn't a bound on the degree, would $Poly(\mathbb{F}^n)$ be infinite dimensional?

Comment: Yes.$ $$ $$ $$ $

Comment: Oh wow, that's quite amazing. Thank you for all the help.